# Ubuntu 12.10 boots to purple or black screen but intermittently boots fine

Tags: 12.10, boot

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [My computer boots to a black screen, what options do I have to fix it?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it)

I have a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10 64bit dual booting with Win7 64bit.
Windows boots fine every time.

When I choose Ubuntu from Grub2 menu it will sometimes boot just fine. Most of the times though it gets stuck at a purple screen with nothing happening and no keys or key combinations working. Other times instead of the purple screen I get a black screen with a flashing cursor at the top. Nothing happens.
I need to hold down the power button to restart and after a couple times of trying it will eventually boot into Ubuntu. Once that happens everything runs without any problems.

I have tried different approaches to fix the problem but to no avail.
I tried removing "quiet splash", used no splash, and nomodeset

What I got from this was seeing all the text of the boot process but more often than not the process gets stuck right after recognizing all the USB ports and devices. If it gets stuck nothing happens (except when i plug in a usb device: it still recognizes it with a new line of text)

In the case when the boot process works, after it lists the usb devices it tells me something like: recovery of read-only filesystem necessary. (its the filesystem that ubuntu runs on)
then it does the recovery and i get: recovery complete.
after that Ubuntu will boot properly and I get to see the login screen.

I have no idea what to do to fix that problem. I have to reboot 3 to 5 times everytime I want to get into Ubuntu and I feel like I'm breaking my new Laptop. (its a lenovo ideapad z580 btw. i5 processor and nvidia gtx640 graphics card)

I hope someone can help me.

Thanks.

Edit: i just got a "failed to enable AA error" message when waking it up from suspend. I don't know if that helps or has anything to do with the boot probs.

Edit 2: When I remove "quiet splash" during boot up I can also see the shut down process in text form. I just realized I'm getting a "mount: / is busy" line before shutting down. Does this have anything to do with the recovery process that it runs through when booting up doesn't get stuck??? 
what can I do?

Edit 3: Problem gets annoying. Did a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.10 64 bits once again! Problem persists.

Really nobody can help????

Comment: its not a duplicate because all those options in the other post didn't solve the problem!!!

Comment: I think i might have solved the problem: 
I added boot options in `/etc/default/grub`.

I removed `quiet splash` and instead use `acpi_osi=linux` and `acpi_backlight=vendor`

the acpi-osi thing lets me boot and the backlight thing lets me use the brightness-hotkeys.

I hope it stays like this.
I'll write again if the boot problem appears again. but up until now I have gone through several reboots without it getting stuck. This hasn't happened before.
I hope the acpi_osi=linux setting doesn't disable anything important.

Comment: SOLVED: ´noapic´ did it! but i have the feeling that this option somehow drains battery life